# UICollectionView remove bottom margins / no spacing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView called: `ListaFotos`. That should show the items without margins, I'm changing the layout using the function `ConfigurarCollectionView()` and it is not showing margins on left and right side but when a third item is loaded there is space between the two first items and the third one. The picture is down to explain better my problem, so is the code.

```
//Listas
@IBOutlet weak var ListaFotos: UICollectionView!

//MARK: - ViewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.ListaFotos.delegate = self
    self.ListaFotos.dataSource = self

    ConfigurarCollectionView()
}

//MARK: - CollectionView Config
func ConfigurarCollectionView(){
    let CVLayOut = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    CVLayOut.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    CVLayOut.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0

    CVLayOut.scrollDirection = .vertical
    CVLayOut.itemSize.width = self.ListaFotos.frame.size.width/2
    CVLayOut.itemSize.height = self.ListaFotos.frame.size.width/2

    CVLayOut.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

    self.ListaFotos.collectionViewLayout = CVLayOut
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does your collection view cell have a margin?

Comment: @MikeTaverne No, at least none I'm aware of

Comment: you can set collection view property view minimum spacing for cell and for cells.

Comment: @NidhiPatel Where and how? Is it on the UICollectionViewFlowLayout?